# NetBeans background color for current line executing in debugger

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8.1

In [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/index.html) 8.1, how does one control the background color of the currently executing line of code in the debugger?

[image]

That screenshot is from use of *Norway Today* theme. As you can see the currently executing line is unreadable because of the bright green-yellow background.

I examined the *Settings/Preferences* > *Fonts & Colors* > *Highlighting* items. None of them seemed to be the currently executing line background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Fonts and Colors* -> *Annotations* tab.

Select ***Current Program Counter*** in *Category* List.

Change the background color.
Use the *Apply* button at the bottom.

Note in my test I needed to restart Netbeans after a applying before I saw any effect.